# Three.js: Transparent objects within multiple renderers (WebGLRenderer + CSS3DRenderer)

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I would be very appreciated if you could help me to solve a transparency issue in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mihails/oL0uwtvs/2

```
element.style.opacity = 0.5;
...
matCube.transparent = true;
matCube.opacity = 0.5;
```

See: [Issue details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUa3d.png)

Main challenges:

- Multiple Renderers

  - WebGLRenderer: main Three scene (meshes, bones, animations and etc.)
  - CSS3DRenderer: this will contain CSS3DObjects (div, iframes, embedded videos, html elements like GIFs and etc.)
- All objects are transparent

Many Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: The CSS3DRenderer has no knowledge of the WebGLRenderer's depth buffer.

Comment: Very appreciated for you response. NOTE: Working fine with not-transparent objects and Three.js (R58): https://jsfiddle.net/Mihails/x64tt4zy/

Comment: your JS fiddle adds a plane to the scene that your first example does not. I'm not sure if that will cause what we see. The css3d has no depth buffer access like was said earlier.